# Return link from Hateos

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have this old Spring Hateos code which I want to migrate to the latest version:

```
    Map<String, Link> links = new HashMap<>();

    links.put(Link.REL_NEXT, response.getLink(Link.REL_NEXT));
    links.put(Link.REL_PREVIOUS, response.getLink(Link.REL_PREVIOUS));

    addLink(url, response, links, Link.REL_NEXT);
    addLink(url, response, links, Link.REL_PREVIOUS);

  ....

    private void addLink(String baseUrl, WebResource response, Map<String, Link> links, String rel) {
    if (links.get(rel) == null) {
      return;
    }
    Link link = links.get(rel);
    String href = baseUrl;
    if (link.getHref().contains("?")) {
      href = href + link.getHref().substring(link.getHref().indexOf('?'));
    }
    link = Link.of(href, rel);
    response.add(link);
  }
```

I tried this:

```
    Map<LinkRelation, Optional> links = new HashMap<>();


    links.put(IanaLinkRelations.SELF, response.getLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF));

    links.put(IanaLinkRelations.NEXT, response.getLink(IanaLinkRelations.NEXT));

    links.put(IanaLinkRelations.PREVIOUS, response.getLink(IanaLinkRelations.PREVIOUS));


    addLink(apmCoreBaseUrl, response, links, IanaLinkRelations.SELF);

    addLink(apmCoreBaseUrl, response, links, IanaLinkRelations.NEXT);

    addLink(apmCoreBaseUrl, response, links, IanaLinkRelations.PREVIOUS);


private void addLink(String baseUrl, RegistrationsResource response, Map<LinkRelation, Optional> links, LinkRelation rel) {
    if (links.get(rel) == null) {
      return;
    }
    Link link = links.get(rel);
    String href = baseUrl;
    if (link.getHref().contains("?")) {
      href = href + link.getHref().substring(link.getHref().indexOf('?'));
    }
    link = Link.of(href, rel);
    response.add(link);
  }
```

I get error at this line:

```
Link link = links.get(rel);

Required type:  Link
Provided:       Optional
```

Can you advise what is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: _"As you can see I get error"_ - We can't see... what error?  Do you need to review [ask]?

Comment: The bounty may prevent this question from being closed due the "missing debug information", but it probably it won't yield an answer alike that. Please consider adding a stack-trace.

Comment: `Map<LinkRelation, Optional> links` -> `Link link = links.get(rel);`. Unless `Optional extends Link`, this won't work.

Comment: I agree. Can you advise how this can be solved?

Comment: Use `Optional optional = links.get(rel);`?

Comment: hm... but can I get the link from this Optional Object?

Comment: yes you can  `Link link = links.get(rel).get();`

Comment: @PeterPenzov , based on comments & question, I have suggested one answer, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments & question for migration this is what I am suggesting:

```
Map<LinkRelation, Optional<Link>> links = new HashMap<LinkRelation, Optional<Link>>();

links.put(IanaLinkRelations.SELF, Optional.of(response.getLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF)));

links.put(IanaLinkRelations.NEXT, Optional.of(response.getLink(IanaLinkRelations.NEXT)));

links.put(IanaLinkRelations.PREVIOUS, Optional.of(response.getLink(IanaLinkRelations.PREVIOUS)));
```

....

//calling `addLinlk`

```
addLink(apmCoreBaseUrl, response, links, IanaLinkRelations.SELF);

addLink(apmCoreBaseUrl, response, links, IanaLinkRelations.NEXT);

addLink(apmCoreBaseUrl, response, links, IanaLinkRelations.PREVIOUS);
```

And inside addLink:

```
private void addLink(String baseUrl, RegistrationsResource response, Map<LinkRelation, Optional> links, LinkRelation rel) {

    links.get(rel).ifPresent(x->{
     Link link = x;
     String href = baseUrl;
    if (link.getHref().contains("?")) {
      href = href + link.getHref().substring(link.getHref().indexOf('?'));
    }
    link = Link.of(href, rel);
    response.add(link);
    });
  }
```

Tested with Java 11 & spring-hateoas 1.5.0. If you have any different versions, please let me know.

**Edit**

As per OP mentioned, they are using hateoas version `2.6.7`.
The `response` reference in OP's code is custom class which extending [RepresentationModel](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.html). So `response.getLink(..)` will return type of `Optional<Link>`.
So below workaround will work :

```
Map<LinkRelation, Optional<Link>> links = new HashMap<LinkRelation, Optional<Link>>();

links.put(IanaLinkRelations.SELF, response.getLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF));
```

...

No changes in `addLink` & no changes in calling `addLink` required, my original answer still valid for other operations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I made a small change like this: https://pastebin.com/Vt8GJyWV  I use Java 17 and `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.6.7` Can you advise is this valid change, please? If possible can you test it, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov,  sure let me have a look.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, I have 2 questions : 1. can you please give us details of  `RegistrationnResource` class? From which library you are using this. Or is this your custom class?  2. You put  `response.getLink(..)` directly to HashMap, you can you please share what is class type of `response`  here? Once we have these details, it may be pretty straight forward to resolve your issue.

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/95UJATMV

Comment: Ok, will have a look & keep you posted, if require, we can start a chat conversation later.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, `RegistrationsResource` you shared does not have `add` & `getLink` method. Does that mean it is part of super class which `RegistrationsResource` is using? The reason I am asking this question because I just want to validate your `response.add(link);` & `response.getLink`  method if they are compatible to what you are achieving.

Comment: Moreover, can you please let me know what error you got if you use my code as it is ? will it give you some error?

Comment: Here are the extended methods: https://pastebin.com/hPj3B4wK  and for `getLink` I that this one is used https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.java#L241     and  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.java#L106

Comment: I can't run this code right now because I don't have a test environment.

Comment: Hi @PeterPenzov, I just verified & I can see your code will work, I am modifying my answer to support that evidence.

Comment: Thank you! A well deserved bounty score.

Comment: Thanks, I am honored,  I just edited my answer which will support evidence that `response.getLink(..)` will work.  Please let me know if there any error you faced while running your code, will check on that.